# The height of image is changed by percentage without having any size of height in parent element

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the *percentage value* of image inside flex-item. I know the percent value that depend on the size of parent.
In this problem, the parent of image don't set any size explicitly. The size of image is changed without having any explicit size of height in flex-item (parent of image). Width and height of flex-item is still same as original size of image.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid red;
  background-color: black;
}

.flex-item {
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}

.flex-item-image {
  border: 5px solid magenta;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img class="flex-item-image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/326012/pexels-photo-326012.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried remove flex-item and this problem is disappeared.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid red;
  background-color: black;
}

.flex-item-image {
  border: 5px solid magenta;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <img class="flex-item-image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/326012/pexels-photo-326012.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
</div>
```

Why does the problem only occur when image inside flex-item ?
Outside the strange don't occur.
Thank you so much.

Comment: in second example you are using class flex-item-image, but the class name in ccs is .flex-image, is it a typo?

Comment: @Lety sorry. I edited code.

Comment: _"I tried remove flex-item and this problem is disappeared."_ - you can remove the `height: 50%;` as well then, and nothing changes about the result. So it is really not clear what you actually want to achieve here in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe The strange is the problem that is only occur when inside flex-item. Why does this strange occur ? I wrote 2 situations to compare this strange and I don't understand why does the difference occur between them.

Comment: your should read https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/. the key is: "In-flow children of a flex container are called flex items and are laid out using the flex layout model." (so in the second example image is a flex item) and "When a box is a flex item, flex is consulted instead of the main size property to determine the main size of the box. If a box is not a flex item, flex has no effect." (in the first example image is not a flex item so it doesn't use the flex layout model)

Comment: I added different duplicates, take the time to read them to understand this *little quirk*

Answer (score 0):

Okay in the first scenerio you have a flexBox on **.flex** class then you add a flex-child which is **.flex-item**

So **.flex-item** takes the height of flexBox container as its height and when you declare you image height 50%,  the parent of images height is act like declared and image takes 50% of **flex-item's** height(parent of image).

In second scenerio you declare a flexBox in parent(.flex) but it still does not have any height property so image will not use any percentage height property because parent or grandparent item does not have height declared.

**Percantage height property first go to parent if any height declared there take percentage of its height if not goes to grandparent etc..**

In the example below i add a height property to flexBox(parent)[.flex] item. And image uses 50% of its(parent) height

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid red;
  background-color: black;
  height:1000px; 
}

.flex-item-image {
  border: 5px solid magenta;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
      <img
        class="flex-item-image"
        src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/326012/pexels-photo-326012.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
        alt=""
      />
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the strange in first scenerio. I write second scenerio to compare with first scenerio to show you the strange in the first scenerio.

Comment: that is what i am trying to say. you have to declare an height property in your .flex class @PhongVuong

Comment: The strange occur only image inside flex-item. The strange don't occur if not .flex-item. Why ?

Comment: I dont understand your question @PhongVuong

Comment: let me explain like that. Your image has 500x750 `widthxheight` when you add a flex-child and 500x750 image inside that flex-child(parent of image). Flex-child size himself as images sizes . If the images height is more than 750 flexBox will grow to fit. Than when you change height of image inside parent which have now width of 500px and height of 700 px, image can take 50% of parent height because parent(flex-child) height is declared @PhongVuong